# Simple summation off in certain cases while using native code in android application

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am using C++ native code in an Android app. The function is simple, adds two ternary number and returns the sum.

Problem: while adding 10 and 11, sum should be 21 but my function returns 20. Here is the code for the function.

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_CS474_ternarycalculator_NativeLib_sum(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jint op1, jint op2) {

    int output = convertToDec((int)op1) + convertToDec((int)op2);

    return convertToTern(output);

}
```

If I use `int output = convertToDec(10) + convertToDec(11);` the returned number is correct which leads me to believe that there could be some problem with type conversion from `jint` to `int`. I have typecasted  the `jint` values to `int` but the result is still incorrect (20). Also, since the hardcoded values return correct result the function `convertToDec` and `convertToTern` are working fine too. I have run these functions in gcc and the logic is correct but somehow when used in the native code, it is not producing right result.

Any ideas on what might be the problem?

Comment: Will you show how you are calling the function from Java?

Comment: How about not using C style cast in C++ code? Might not be the reason for wrong conversion but it is strongly discouraged to use C style casts in C++ code.